# Delete rows below threshold value for all txt files in a directory

Tags: r, batch-processing, delete-row

I have 800 txt files in X Y format where X and Y are both numbers. I need to (1) delete rows of data where x<91 for each txt file then (2) write the new txt file based on the original file name.

I successfully made a tidyverse code that does this file by file, which is slower than just manually going through notepad and deleting the offending rows of data. I am having difficulty making the code loop through all of the files in the directory.

Here is the mini code:

```
oldfile<- read_tsv(file='WD130887.txt',col_names=FALSE)
newfile<- filter(oldfile, X1>91)
write_tsv(newfile,path ='E:/Contract Data/Shorea2/edited/WD130887.txt')
```

and it works exactly as it should. It places my new, edited file in a new directory so that nothing is overwritten.
Output:

```
> write_tsv(newfile,path ='E:/Contract Data/Shorea2/edited/Shorea sp_WD130887.txt')
> oldfile<- read_tsv(file='Shorea sp_WD130887.txt',col_names=FALSE)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_double(),
  X2 = col_double()
)
> head(oldfile,n=5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     X1     X2
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  89.0  1502.
2  89.1  5791.
3  90.1 20390.
4  91.1   760.
5  93.0 11748.
> newfile<- filter(oldfile, X1>91)
> head(newfile,n=5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     X1     X2
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  91.1   760.
2  93.0 11748.
3  94.1  5183.
4  95.0  4021.
5  95.1   864.
> write_tsv(newfile,path ='E:/Contract Data/Shorea2/edited/Shorea sp_WD130887.txt')
```

My attempt at doing this to the whole directory landed me here:

```
path <- "E:/Contract Data/Shorea2"
fs <-list.files(path, pattern=glob2rx("*.txt$")) #create list of my txt files
for (f in fs){
  fname <- file.path(path, f)
  df <- read_tsv(fname,col_names=FALSE) #open each txt file
  df <- filter(fname,X1>91) #apply tidyverse filter
  write_tsv(df, fname, row.names=FALSE) #write new txt file, I gave up on new directory
}
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Which I believe means that the code is now looking at the file names instead of the value of the rows. Help is appreciated! I am sure this is a simple problem and I am missing something obvious.

Comment: `filter`'s first argument needs to be a `data.frame`/`tibble`. Try `df <- filter(df, X1>91)` instead of `df <- filter(fname,X1>91)` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: I also ended up having to remove the `row.names=FALSE` in the write, but that worked beautifully. Thank you!